# Proper use of NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, filtering, exists

I have two tables -

```
member_master
-----------------------------
member_id, ( PK )
branch_id, ( PK )
name member_id, 


member_photo 
-----------------------------
member_id, ( FK )
branch_id, ( FK )
photo_index, 
photo_file
```

Each entry in `member_master` has zero or more corresponding entries in `member_photo` table.

I have two requirements :

1. Get all the entries from member_master which have at least one entry in `member_photo` table. I am getting the correct result using the following SQL command

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT member_master.member_id,member_master.branch_id,name
    FROM member_master, member_photo
    WHERE member_master.branch_id=1 
    AND EXISTS
    (
      SELECT member_photo.member_id 
      WHERE member_master.member_id = member_photo.member_id 
      AND member_master.branch_id = member_photo.branch_id
    )
   ;
   ```
2. Get all the entries from `member_master` which DO NOT have any entry in `member_photo` table. I am using the following SQL command

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT member_master.member_id,member_master.branch_id,name FROM member_master, member_photo
   WHERE member_master.branch_id=1 
   AND NOT EXISTS
   (
     SELECT member_photo.member_id 
     WHERE member_master.member_id = member_photo.member_id 
     AND member_master.branch_id = member_photo.branch_id
   )
   ;
   ```

The only difference is I have added a NOT before EXISTS command.
But unfortunately it does not give me the correct result. It simply returns all the rows in the table.

Please note that I am using SQL Server Express 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it without joining the tables, just select from the master table and add check for the photo table, like this:

```
SELECT
  m.member_id,
  m.branch_id,
  m.name 
FROM 
  member_master m
WHERE 
  m.branch_id=1 AND 
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 from member_photo p where
    m.member_id = p.member_id AND m.branch_id = p.branch_id)
```

And similarly the other case:

```
SELECT
  m.member_id,
  m.branch_id,
  m.name 
FROM 
  member_master m
WHERE 
  m.branch_id=1 AND 
  not EXISTS (SELECT 1 from member_photo p where
    m.member_id = p.member_id AND m.branch_id = p.branch_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Required `SQL` query is:

```
SELECT 
      member_id,
      branch_id,
      name 
FROM member_master
WHERE member_master.branch_id=1
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT member_photo.member_id 
                   WHERE member_master.member_id = member_photo.member_id
                       AND member_master.branch_id = member_photo.branch_id)
```